# Is there a bug of InverseDistanceTransform?

Tags: image-processing

This is a example of [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseDistanceTransform.html) about `InverseDistanceTransform`.
[image]

But this is my picture

[image]

But it doesn't work:

```
InverseDistanceTransform[pic, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance]
```

[image]

Comment: If you evaluate `Max[ImageData[pic]]` with the image in the documentation, you get 13, i.e. the values of the white pixels are larger than 1, namely the disk radii in pixels. I'm guessing your image contains values between 0 and 1, so `InverseDistanceTransform` creates disks with radii between 0 and 1

Comment: Try e.g. `InverseDistanceTransform[ImageMultiply[pic, 10]]` to get disks with radius 10

Comment: @nikie Oh,Thanks a lot.I think you should post a answer about this to help the reader.And I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you evaluate `Max[ImageData[pic]]` with the image in the documentation, you get 13, i.e. the values of the white pixels are larger than 1, namely the disk radii in pixels. I'm guessing your image contains values between 0 and 1, so `InverseDistanceTransform` creates disks with radii between 0 and 1